# Is it possible to pipe large Google keyword search volumes through one Google Ads account

Tags: google-api, keyword, google-ads-api

I am creating a web platform on which we would like to let our users (many thousands) use the Google Keyword Planer tool via API to look up word statisks and also suggest new words, if possible.

From what I can read in Google's API docs you have to have an account with Google to use the KW planer. Isn't it possible to somehow use KW planer via API without have each user creating a Google Ads account? Paid or not paid.

Our new online service can of course have a hidden central Google account as long as we can provide volume searches as explained above. But it looks like Google slows down search speed if you do too many searches, and we can't have that.

I am happy for any suggestion on how to get access to the KW planer via API for large volume use. Semrush does something like this. They surely must get their data from Google.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

It's true, for bulk KW planning results you need the create users own account programatically under your main manager account and delete them later programatically. It will help you from slowing down as your KW planner calls going to be called with different accounts each time.

Best!
Makanist